# Deleting unreferenced dynamic memory

Tags: c++, dynamic, memory-leaks

If i have the following part of the code in C++:

```
class X {
   ...
};

class Y {
public:
  Y(X*) {...};
  ...
};

void main () 
{
  X* px = new X;
  new Y(px);
  ... // ***
}
```

How to delete object of class Y which was created in main? (***)
It is only allowed to add new lines of code instead of ..., not to change existing ones.

Comment: Looks like homework to me, given the slightly crazy architecture. Please retag, or explain what the real purpose of this code is ;-)

Comment: Also, what have you tried? What has gone wrong? You've phrased your question as if you're expecting a complete solution to be implemented for you.

Comment: yea srry, i changed it now :) and it is an exam question :)

Comment: why are you not allowed to change the existing code?

Comment: you could globally overload operator `new` and `delete` and keep track of the memory allocated

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer** Never write code like this; avoid dynamic objects when you can, and if you really need them, always use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to manage them in a straightforward, exception-safe way.

Replace the first `...` with:

```
#define void int
```

since `void main ()` is invalid, and my compiler rejects it. This might not be necessary if your compiler is sufficiently dysfunctional.

Replace the second with:

```
WTF() = this;
```

to stash a pointer to the object that will need deleting in a static variable, defined later. Note that this only allows us to control one such object at a time; but, given the insane requirements, I can't think of a better way to make it available. If the constructor argument were available, then we could stash it in a non-static member of `X` instead; but the argument is unnamed, so we can't do anything with it.

Repace the third with:

```
static Y *& WTF() {static Y * y; return y;}
```

giving us a static variable to stash the pointer in. It can't be a global or static class member, since they must be defined outside the class definition.

Now we can replace the fourth with:

```
delete Y::WTF();
delete px;
```

Without the weird requirements, you could replace the whole mess with:

```
int main() {
    X x;
    Y y(&x);
}
```

The lesson from all this is: memory management in C++ is quite straightforward if you do it the right way, and insanely convoluted if you do it the wrong way.

Comment: +1 and http://images.wikia.com/creepypasta/images/5/56/Disgusted-oh-god-why-text.png

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Mike's answer, but I'd like to give an example of a *working* code, as opposed to Luchian's

```
class X {
public: void*data;
};

class Y {
public:
  Y(X*px)
  { px->data = this; };
};

int main () 
{
  X* px = new X;
  new Y(px);
  delete static_cast<Y*>(px->data);
  return 0;
}
```